# How do we know which variable to substitute in integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

Often times, I encountered questions that requires Integration by substitution; however, I am still somewhat confused regarding the choice of values that should be substituted by u since it differs by question. Here are my solutions to two different questions.

FIRST QUESTION:
$$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$$
$$u = 1 + \cos^2x $$
$$du = -2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx $$
$$-du = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx $$
$$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$$
The trigonometric identity states that:
$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
Therefore:
$$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$$
$$-\int_{}^{}\dfrac{1}{u}du$$
$$-\ln(u)+C$$
$$-\ln(1+\cos^2(x))+C$$

SECOND QUESTION:

$$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$$
$$u = \cos(x) $$
$$du = -\sin(x)dx $$
$$-du = \sin(x)dx $$
$$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$$
$$-\int_{}^{}\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}du$$
$$-\arctan(u)+C$$
$$-\arctan(\cos(x))+C$$

We can see that the first question requires me to substitute $1 + cos^2(x)$ with $u$. Whereas the second question requires me to substitute $cos(x)$ instead. I found them by simply using trial and error, but is there a specific guidelines that I can follow instead?

Comment: For the first question, I would expand $\sin (2x)=2\sin(x) \cos(x)$.  Then I would notice that I have a rational function in $\cos (x)$ times $d(\cos(x))$  There are often multiple ways to the answer.  The second yields to the same insight.  You just try things until one works. Integration, unlike differentiation, is not turning a crank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of seeking out a certain "pattern".  There are two questions you should ask yourself before making a substitution:

1. What is $du$ in terms of $dx$ and would it be easy to plug this into the integral?
2. Does this choice of $u$ make my life easier?  i.e., once I make the substitution, will I be able to solve it?

Often times, there is more than one choice of $u$.  And, often times, it is a bit of trial and error unless you're really smart.  For example, if I were given the integral without any hints, I probably would've guessed to use $u = \cos(x)$ since it's clear to me that the derivative of $\cos(x)$, which is $-\sin(x)$, is present in the original integrand.  This means that I can easily plug in $du$ into the integral.

It turns out that the derivative of $1 + \cos^2(x)$ is also present, but this isn't immediately obvious to me so I wouldn't have tried that.

Let's look at a different integral:

$$ \int \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx $$

The first thing that I notice with an integral is that the denominator is "ugly" and makes the problem difficult to solve.  **More importantly, we see that the numerator is like a derivative of the denominator -- it is one power lower than the denominator.**  These two attributes make the denominator a prime candidate for substitution.

Now, we have a few choices, such as $u = 1 + x^2$ or $u = x^2$.  In either case, $du = 2x dx$, which can be rearranged to give $du/2 = x dx$.  Given these two choices, I would rather do $u = 1 + x^2$ simply because it makes the expression simpler in the end.  But either is fine.

Making the substitution gives:
$$ \int \frac{du/2}{u} $$
or
$$ \int \frac{1}{2u} du = \frac{1}{2}\ln u = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + x^2 \right) $$
You should see that, with roughly the same amount of work, we can arrive at this solution using $u = x^2$.

To summarize and answer your question:

1. Yes, it does take some trial and error sometimes.
2. Look for the presence of something and its derivative.  If there's an $x^2$ that you want to get rid of, is there also an $x$ in the integrand multiplying the whole expression?  If there's an $\cos(x)$ that you want to get rid of, is there also a $\sin(x)$ in the integrand multiplying the whole expression?
3. See if your substitution makes the integral easier to solve.  (This ties in with the trial and error part.)
4. There are often multiple choices for $u$ that are good.  It doesn't really matter which one you choose in that case.